# Why is IE8 not loading my eot files?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fonts

I downloaded some otf fonts and then converted them to eot using: https://onlinefontconverter.com but when I view the site in IE8, the fonts do not show (they show in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Android). Something must be wrong with either my code or the eot. Does anyone know what's wrong?

**(Download Roboto here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto )**

**(Convert it here: https://onlinefontconverter.com )**

**STYLES.CSS**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    src: url("Roboto-Condensed.eot");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    src: url("Roboto-Condensed.ttf");
}

.myDiv
{
    font-family: RobotoCondensed, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

**index.html (relevant code)**

```
<div class="myDiv">Some font in here that shows incorrectly as Arial!</div>
```

The stylesheet and font are in the same folder.

Comment: Why isn't the `font-family = Roboto-Condensed` ?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: Have you tried using the font generator at Font Squirrel?  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator  -  gives you all the necessary fonts and css for all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. It looks like the problem was the font converter. The eot file was not being recognized as valid by IE. Thanks to "Joel Eckroth" for suggesting I try other converters.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
        @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'RobotoCondensed';
        src: url('Roboto-Condensed.eot');
  src: url('Roboto-Condensed.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Roboto-Condensed.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Roboto-Condensed.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Roboto-Condensed.svg#') format('svg');

}

    .myDiv
    {
        font-family: RobotoCondensed, Arial, Helvetica;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #e8e8e8;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem and no amount of tweaking and web research helped
Until I edited **head** tag to include **meta**

```
<head>

   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

</head>
```

The meta tag solved problem and every variation worked!

Variation 1

```
<style type="text/css">

  @font-face

  {

    font-family: 'SolaimanLipi';

    src: url('SolaimanLipi.eot');

    src: local('SolaimanLipi'),url('SolaimanLipi.ttf') format('truetype');

  }

  @font-face

  {

    font-family: 'Yogesh';

    src: url('CDACOTYGN.eot');

    src: url('CDACOTYGN.ttf') format('truetype');

  }

</style>
```

Variation 2

```
<style type="text/css">

  @font-face{

    font-family: 'solaimanlipi';

    src: url('cdacotygn-webfont.eot');

    src: url('cdacotygn-webfont?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

         url('solaimanlipi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

         url('solaimanlipi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

         url('solaimanlipi-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');

  }

  @font-face {

    font-family: 'cdacotygn';

    src: url('cdacotygn-webfont.eot');

    src: url('cdacotygn-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

         url('cdacotygn-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

         url('cdacotygn-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),

         url('cdacotygn-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');

  }

</style>
```

We think complex but often needle in haystack is elsewhere **head** **meta** tags

You may try and view source
http://www.weloveseppa.com/jnc/jncTryBangla.html
http://www.weloveseppa.com/jnc/try1/jncTryBangla.html

Works in all the browsers including the old IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
font-family: "RobotoCondensed", Arial, Helvetica;
```

The quotes should force it as your primary option

Comment: No. Whether you use quotes or not has no effect whatsoever on which of these fonts is chosen. Quotes help the parser (and the casual reader) determine what the font names are exactly, but once the names are parsed, there's no difference in how they are used.