# IIS font face issue with IE8 eot

Tags: css, iis, internet-explorer-8, font-face, eot

I'm having a strange problem with an ASP MVC 4 .Net website using web fonts.

The site references FontAwesome and Roboto, and renders as expected in FireFox, Chrome and IE10, but needs to work in IE8+ as well.

**it's worth noting when the html source is saved locally it works in IE8, just not when returned by IIS**.

It seems as though the .eot is not being sent to the browser when served up by IIS (7 or debugging in IIS Express in VS2010). But woff and ttf return as expected (confirmed using Fiddler and Firebug).

I already have:

- mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" /> in the web.config.
- Build Action set to 'Content' for .css and font files.
- css @fontface declared as:

  ```
  @font-face
  {
      font-family:'FontAwesome';
      src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');
      src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'),
      url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'),
      url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');
      font-weight:normal;font-style:normal
  }
  ```

401:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 14:48:51 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

200:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 10:43:18 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "067e7eb1198ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Persistent-Auth: false
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYGgMIGdoAMKAQChCwYJKoZIgvcSAQICooGIBIGFYIGCBgkqhkiG9xIBAgICAG9zMHGgAwIBBaEDAgEPomUwY6ADAgEXolwEWl1ljYO00B8Uphl5NsfdQu3+5k9yJlSL2JTRqcofSeQ9oylbvSVbHKLWvBrFned5/+Sxodxe6MkY+IB0xEvtp3FVXB4HM3MuanzmqUo7p58L+wDxxG7hdnRgsA==
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 15:36:17 GMT
Content-Length: 29360

�r���q����������������������LP�����������������������#M
�������������������F�o�n�t�A�w�e�s�o�m�e����R�e�g�u�l�a�r���$�V�e�r�s�i�o�n� �3�.�1�.�0� �2�0�1�3���&�F�o�n�t�A�w�e�s�o�m�e� �R�e�g�u�l�a�r�����BSGP�������������������q��q��e�����Y�D
M�F�x���>��ޝ��Ə)[1ɵH���-A)F��ٜ1��.�/
d�U'�&a
```

Comment: When you make a request directly to the .eot file what headers do you see?

Comment: They're the request headers?  What about the response ones?  Also, add this stuff into your question and use code formatting so it's easier to read.

Comment: my bad, sorry.  i get a 401 and a 304 in that order, described above then prompted to download the .eot,  Thanks

Comment: OK, clear your cache so you can see the actual headers for the .eot file rather than the 304.

Comment: That's changed to a 200 response. Updated above with first few lines of content...

Comment: I'm stumped then, everything looks right to me.  Have you tried adding `local("☺")` as per [this article](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/)?  Also there's a big list of gotchas at the end of [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is IE8 not loading my eot files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627899/why-is-ie8-not-loading-my-eot-files)